# Doctrine mysql cascade get restored

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, orm, php-7

I was trying to remove an entity (A) that has a relation to other entities (B) which has an on delete cascade configured towards entity A. When removing multiple entities of the type of entity A with flushes in between, removed entities be restored.

For example, in the following situation:

```
$orm->remove($actionButton);
$orm->flush();

$orm->remove($actionButton2);
$orm->flush();
```

This will result in the following queries:

```
"START TRANSACTION" 
 DELETE FROM action_button WHERE action_button_id = ?

array (size=1)
  0 => int 6

"COMMIT" 
"START TRANSACTION" 
 INSERT INTO action_button (action_button_color, media_id) VALUES (?, ?)

array (size=2)
  1 => string '#000' (length=4)
  2 => null

DELETE FROM action_button WHERE action_button_id = ?

array (size=1)
  0 => int 7

"COMMIT"
```

With the following entities:

```
/**
 * ActionButtonLanguage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="action_button_language", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="language_id", columns={"language_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ActionButtonLanguage
{
    /**
     * @var \Education
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ActionButton", inversedBy="actionButtonLanguages", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="action_button_id", referencedColumnName="action_button_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     * })
     */
    private $actionButton;

....

}

/**
 * ActionButton
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="action_button")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ActionButton
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ActionButtonLanguage", mappedBy="actionButton", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $actionButtonLanguages;

....

}
```

Why are these entities restored and how can I prevent that they will be restored when I flush in-between?

Edit:

Test code:

```
//Test area
$language = new Language();
$language->setLanguageName('EN');

$actionButton = new ActionButton();
$actionButton->setActionButtonColor('#000');
$orm->persist($actionButton);

$actionButtonLanguage = new ActionButtonLanguage();
$actionButtonLanguage->setActionButtonName('test');
$actionButtonLanguage->setActionButton($actionButton);
$actionButtonLanguage->setLanguage($language);
$orm->persist($actionButtonLanguage);


$actionButton2 = new ActionButton();
$actionButton2->setActionButtonColor('#000');
$orm->persist($actionButton2);

$actionButtonLanguage2 = new ActionButtonLanguage();
$actionButtonLanguage2->setActionButtonName('test');
$actionButtonLanguage2->setActionButton($actionButton2);
$actionButtonLanguage2->setLanguage($language);
$orm->persist($actionButtonLanguage2);
$orm->flush();

$ormHelper = new \CMS\includes\database\ORMHelper();
$ormHelper->enableLogging(1);

$orm->remove($actionButton);
$orm->flush();

$orm->remove($actionButton2);
$orm->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

These entities restored because something went wrong during flush operation. Maybe the cascade delete failed or another joins prevent the operation. 
Are you sure the cascade have been generated in your db schema?

Comment: The cascade is inside the database. But I think that the entity that was removed by the cascade is still managed and that entity will restore the removed entity because it is still linked.

Comment: Removing both entities with only one flush will work.